# Power BI - dynamic "Goals"label in a KPI visual

Tags: powerbi-desktop, kpi

Is it possible to make the "Goals" label dynamic?  Instead of showing a static text like "Previous month" (or whatever), I would like it to show the name of the previous month.  Setting up a measure like that is trivial, but is there a way to put it in a label instead of a static text?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would really like this feature as well. Unfortunately, it doesn't exist. Head over to https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/ and submit it.

As a possible work-around, you could remove the label text and put a measure into a card visual and then align that. It's not a great option though as it won't be there in focus mode if users click into that. Sadly, there are a few other idea posts to group multiple visuals into a single focus mode, but they have very few votes. You can of course turn off focus mode if you don't want users to use that.